# Proper actions in complex geometry

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, covering-spaces, quotient-spaces, holomorphic-bundles

> [skip to next blockquote for the actual question]

---

Complex geometry books often treat quotients by 'properly discontinuous' actions, such as the action of a lattice $L \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ on the complex line. The resulting canonical projection
$$p \colon \mathbb{C} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{C}/L$$
satisfies the universal property of topological quotients and is a covering map.

Using this, it is very easy to show that there exists a (essentially unique) Riemann surface structure on the quotient such that the canonical projection is a holomorphic map (uniqueness follows from the fact that, in this case, the canonical projection is a quotient in the category of Riemann surfaces).

Indeed, the structure can be defined by taking as charts the local inverses of the canonical projection.

Since the map $p$ is

- a quotient
- a covering map (hence we have lifting of maps)

it is very easy to study the quotient spaces $\mathbb{C}/L$.

---

This is interesting, but in complex geometry we also have to deal with quotients by 'geometric groups' and projections such as
$$p \colon \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}
    \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n.$$
The right generalization seems to be that of 'proper action'.

The only book I found treating this subject was Lee's book on smooth manifolds. I checked many complex geometry books but I found nothing.

---

> Can someone point me to other books / resources
>   (preferably in the context of complex geometry)
>   for quotients by complex Lie groups acting properly,
>   and to an analogue theory of covering maps in this context?
>   The endgoal would be to have tools
>   in order to study quotients without continuously using charts.
>
> I'm also interested in any kind of information
>   we can find about the quotient using our knowledge of
>   the étalé space.
>
> For example, it would be nice to deduce informations about
>   the holomorphic vector bundles over
>   $\mathbb{P}^n$ from those over $\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$.